# Combine subclassed modelforms into parent model

Tags: django

I'm using django's form wizard for a survey, and I want to save the entire survey into a single model. I've split the model into multiple forms, in order to have a subset of the model in each FormWizard step.
The question is, how do I combine them back together at the end?
My models.py looks like this:

```
class BigSurvey(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField()
    field2 = models.TextField()
    ...
    field40 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

and my forms.py is like this:

```
class FirstPageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BigSurvey
        fields = ('field1', 'field2')

class SecondPageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BigSurvey
        fields = ('field3', 'field4')
```

And so on, for four forms and 30 fields total. The fields of each subclassed model form, combined, are all of the fields in the BigSurvey model.

This allows me to spit the BigSurvey into four steps. Form wizard returns an object form_list, which is a list of each of the four forms (FirstPageForm, SecondPageForm, etc).

How can I combine these four forms into a single BigSurvey object to save?

**UPDATE:**
Solved by iterating over forms and fields and populating a new form with a dictionary of values. Populating by using setattr (as per Colleen's answer below) results in an unbound form.
My working solution:

```
newvalues={}
for form in form_list:
    for field in form.cleaned_data.keys():
        newvalues[field]=form.cleaned_data[field]   
newform = QuestForm(newvalues)
newform.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over all of the fields in each form and assign BigSurvey fields to their values.

```
bg = BigSurvey()

for form in form_list
    for field in form.cleaned_data.keys():
        setattr(bg, field, form.cleaned_data[field])

bg.save()
```

Comment: Solved it. Thanks! There's still the problem that if I add a field in BigSurvery, I have to by-hand add it into one of the subforms, which doesn't seem too DRY... but I can live with that.
Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that there's a way to get around that... glad I could help :)

Comment: Actually, there was an error with your answer (updating my question above to reflect the solution).
When you populate the form using settattr, the form is still unbound (don't know why), so calling bg.is_valid() returns false (calling bg.is_bound() returns false as well).
The answer is to create a dictionary with the iterated fields/values, and populate bg with the dictionary when creating it.